# FormData won't load inputs of form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

*My Code*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="form-sample">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="sample-text" />
      <input type="radio" name="sample-radio" value="yes" />
      <input type="radio" name="sample-radio" value="no" />
      <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple" />
      <input type="submit" value="Fetch Data" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    function onSubmitForm(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const fD = new FormData(document.querySelector("#form-sample form"));
      console.log(fD.entries()); // get an empty FormData Iterator
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
      document.querySelector("#form-sample form").addEventListener("submit", onSubmitForm, false);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Why doesn't FormData load the `<form>` inputs and why is that not returning an exception?

Actually trying this code on latest Firefox version (v95.0)

Comment: How are you determining the FormData iterator is empty, just from the console.log? I would use `console.log(Array.from(fD.entries()).length)`.

Comment: Thanks ! @HereticMonkey that resolve all my questions

Comment: `<input>`s are hardcoded HTML so naturally they rendered as usual. Do you mean loaded so you'll see them logged in `console`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. You can iterate through the Iterator:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries
2. You can get the values one by one:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get

Comment: The OP claims the iterator is empty. Also, answers which are just links to documentation are rarely good answers. Better to show code demonstrating how to use the linked commands.

Comment: "answers which are just links to documentation are rarely good answers" - Unfortunately not everybody reads through the documentation thoroughly before asking. Anyway, I could not have prepared better code example than the ones being in the documentation.

Comment: You could have prepared an example using the OP's code. They're already using `entries`; it's just a matter of typing `fD.get('nameOfElement')`...